# What is the rejection region for this test?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

A sample of size 16 was randomly drawn from a normal population with known standard deviation σ = 5. The sample mean is equal to 20.5. The researcher wants to run the followingz-test(α=5%): H0 :μ=20versusHa :μ<20.
What is the rejection region for this test?
a. x < 17.55.
b. x < 17.94.
c. x < 18.05.
d. x < 18.44.

The right answer is answer b, but i don´t understand how they arrived to that answer, so any help explaining that would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Add the `self-study` tag and take a look at the tag [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 0):

The region of rejection will be such that its probability under null hypothesis ($H_0:\mu=20$) is $\alpha=0.05$. Now, remember that:

$$\dfrac{\bar x - 20}{5/\sqrt{16}}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

So, with probability $\alpha=0.05$ on the left tail, we have:

$$\dfrac{\bar x - 20}{5/\sqrt{16}}<-z_{0.05}$$

From a standard normal distribution table, we have $z_{0.05}=1.64$. Therefore, solving for $\bar x$, we have:

$$\bar x < 20 - 1.64\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{16}}=17.94$$

Therefore, if $\mu$ is actually $20$, we have a probability of $5\%$ of having $\bar x<17.94$. This is the rejection region for $\alpha=5\%$.